# subprocess.check_output(cmd) doesn't execute for tar -C option

Tags: python-3.x, subprocess

I am trying to run the following command using `subprocess.check_output()`. The command (shown below) works fine if run directly in bash :

```
tar -C /tmp/models/  -czvf model.tar.gz .
```

It also runs fine if I don't use the "C" option when run via subprocess.

```
cmd = ['tar', 'czf', "/tmp/model.tar.gz", "/tmp/models/"]
output = subprocess.check_output(cmd).decode("utf-8").strip() # Works
```

But when I try to use the -C option with the above tar command, I get an exception which says `tar: Must specify one of -c, -r, -t, -u, -x`.

```
cmd = ['tar', 'C', '/tmp/models', 'cf', 'model.tar.gz', '.'] # fails. Other variations of this fail too.
```

How do I run the above tar command using subprocess correctly?. Thanks.

I am using python3.8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the dashes `-` should be specified:

```sh
$ tar C whatever czvf thing.tar .
tar: Must specify one of -c, -r, -t, -u, -x

$ tar C whatever -czvf thing.tar .
tar: could not chdir to 'whatever'
```

So the command should look like this:

```
cmd = ['tar', '-C', '/tmp/models', '-cf', 'model.tar.gz', '.']
```

Comment: Thanks. This works.. weirdly,  Looks like I'll have to look at the docs more closely, coz the examples I've seen doesn't use "-"